# BadParcelableException without using Parcelables in the project

Tags: android, cordova, android-instant-apps

My Android app is receiving crash reports caused by "BadParcelableException". I'm not using Parcelables in my project and the stack trace doesn't contain any of my code, so I don't know how to debug this. The app is a Cordova app, and the crashes are coming from the instant version of the app (but this might be because most of the users are using the instant version). So far I've seen Android versions 9 and 8.1. Here is the stack trace:

```
android.os.BadParcelableException: 
  at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator (Parcel.java:2855)
  at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable (Parcel.java:2781)
  at android.os.Parcel.readValue (Parcel.java:2684)
  at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal (Parcel.java:3053)
  at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked (BaseBundle.java:288)
  at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel (BaseBundle.java:232)
  at android.os.Bundle.filterValues (Bundle.java:389)
  at android.os.Bundle.filterValues (Bundle.java:399)
  at android.content.Intent.removeUnsafeExtras (Intent.java:8451)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRequestAssistContextExtras (ActivityThread.java:3403)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1906)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7078)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:974)
```

What could be causing this? Is there something I can do to fix the issue?